# `wget -U` and `curl -A` both receives 403 forbidden response

Tags: wget, curl, 23.04

I have tried both `curl -A` and `wget -U` and both receive `403 forbidden` response. The agent I use is `'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'` I have also tried [wget or curl gives 403:Forbidden while downloading file from OneDrive for business](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205418/wget-or-curl-gives-403forbidden-while-downloading-file-from-onedrive-for-busine)

Browser is able to download the image.

Comment: Nobody is able to tell you the reason without knowing the specific site you tried to download from. The short answer is: configuration of the site prohibits downloading with these tools somehow - we can't know how.